# Calculate path length (distance in kilometers) using Geotools Dijkstra shortest path finder

Tags: java, path, distance, dijkstra, geotools

I use Geotools API to calculate the shortest path. I have this portion of code:

```
 DijkstraShortestPathFinder dijkstra = new DijkstraShortestPathFinder(network, n_end, weighter);
 dijkstra.calculate();
 Path myPath=dijkstra.getPath(n_start);
```

How can I calculate de length of myPath?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the length of myPath as follows:`

```
                 Iterator pathIterator = myPath.getEdges().iterator();       
                 double length=0;
                 while (pathIterator.hasNext())
                 {
                     Edge edge= (Edge) pathIterator.next();
                     SimpleFeature feature = (SimpleFeature) edge.getObject();
                     Geometry geom = (Geometry ) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
                     length+=geom.getLength();
                 }
```